# Quelle est la différence entre « adhérent », « partisan » et « adepte» ?

Tags: vocabulaire

Pourquoi faut-il dire « adeptes du cinéma » et non « adhérents du cinéma ». Quand est-ce qu'on utilise partisan?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Par **conviction** (soutenir une association) et/ou par **intérêt** (bénéficier des avantages liés à une adhésion), et généralement en contrepartie du paiement d'une cotisation annuelle, on peut être **adhérent** d'une cinémathèque.

> Cet accès est réservé aux **adhérents de la cinémathèque** de Bretagne.
>   Cet espace vous permet de consulter la base documentaire, la photothèque et de visionner les films de la cinémathèque de Bretagne disponibles sur le site.

Site web: [Cinémathèque de Bretagne](https://www.cinematheque-bretagne.fr/Acc%C3%A8s-%C3%A0-la-collection-films-1051-0-0-0.html)

2. Par **conviction**, on peut être (ou ne pas être) **partisan** d'un certain type de cinéma :

> Fervent admirateur d’Emile Cohl et de Charlie Chaplin, Dubout a apprécié au plus haut point le dessin animé et les films muets, proches des arts graphiques. Pagnol, en revanche, fut un fervent **partisan du cinéma parlant** qui, d’après lui, avait le don de faire revivre les acteurs, par-delà la mort, éternellement…

[Marcel Pagnol et Albert Dubout : la dynamique de la création*, Solange VERNOIS, 2018](http://tierce.edel.univ-poitiers.fr/index.php?id=241)

3. Par **goût**, on peut être **adepte** d'un certain type de cinéma : muet, en 3D, etc.

> 15 choses à savoir sur Quentin Tarantino
>   ...
>   C'est un **adepte du cinéma de genre**.

https://www.linternaute.com/cinema/star-cinema/1035582-15-choses-a-savoir-sur-quentin-tarantino/

Comment: Excellente réponse, +1

Answer (score 2):

Les définitions du TLFi qui se rapportent au sens courants sont dans les encadrements jaunes.

> **ADHÉRENT**
>   A. Personne(s) que lient des intérêts, un idéal, des sentiments communs
>   B. Spéc. Membre d'une association, d'une organisation politique, syndicale, religieuse, etc. dotée de statuts

En continuation de l'explication de la partie « B » de la définition, l'adhérent est celui qui est lié à un système par des liens plus ou moins formels souvent sous la forme de statuts écrits et qui de par son adhésion est tenu de respecter des règles et formalités. Un adhérent est donc dans l'ensemble soumis assez strictement à une autorité. La motivation pour l'adhésion a généralement un aspect pratique.

Il n'est donc pas question de dire « adhérent au cinéma » puisque il n'y a besoin d'aucun lien à une autorité quelconque pour profiter du cinéma ni de règles.

> **PARTISAN**
>   b) Personne qui prend parti pour quelqu'un (dont il partage, défend les idées), pour un système, une doctrine, une théorie.

Le partisan peut être lié à un système, mais d'une autre espèce que le système auquel l'adhérent est lié ; ces systèmes sont de toutes sortes mais d'habitude ils existent en tant qu'alternatives non commerciales mais concurrentes à d'autres systèmes. Le partisan est quelqu'un qui aura toujours un rôle plus actif que l'adhérent, quelqu'un de qui l'on escompte de pouvoir défendre ce pour quoi il est partisan, de participer à cette défense dans le cadre de l'organisation ou de son propre chef. Lorsqu'il s'agit d'une doctrine ou d'une théorie non soutenue par une organisation, ses partisan sont des personnes telles les partisans rassemblés par une organisation, sauf qu'ils ne promulguent et défendent leur doctrine ou théorie que selon leur seule propre initiative. La motivation de la partisannerie est  essentiellement idéologique.

En ce qui concerne le cinéma en tant que spectateur, il n'est pas question de théorie et de doctrine et donc pas question de dire « partisan du cinéma ».

> **ADEPTE**
>   A *vieilli* Personne initiée à une doctrine ésotérique, aux secrets d'un art; membre d'une société secrète
>   B Membre d'un groupe plus ou moins fermé (secte religieuse, loge maçonnique). Partisan d'une doctrine religieuse, politique ou scientifique, du maître qui la professe

L'adepte est quelqu'un un peu comme le partisan, la différence importante suivante devant être bien entendue ; le système ou la doctrine ou l'art qu'il/elle fait sien/sienne jusqu'à un certain point n'est pas véritablement établie sur la base d'une concurrence avec d'autres doctrines ou arts ; cela est très vrai dans le cas de l'art, et le reste essentiellement dans le cas des religions. Cela est aussi vrai pour les sciences : on dira « [partisan](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=adepte+du+darwinisme%2C+partisan+du+darwinisme&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpartisan%20du%20darwinisme%3B%2Cc0) du Darwinisme » et pas, ou très peu « adepte du Darwinisme » et de même « [partisans](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=partisans+de+la+relativit%C3%A9%2Cadeptes+de+la+relativit%C3%A9&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpartisans%20de%20la%20relativit%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0) de la relativité » et pas « adeptes de la relativité ». Cela semble être confirmé pour la politique : on dit « [partisans](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=adeptes+du+pacifisme%2Cpartisans+du+pacifisme&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpartisans%20du%20pacifisme%3B%2Cc0) du pacifisme » et pratiquement pas « adeptes du pacifisme ». On dit par exemple « adeptes de la sorcellerie », « adeptes de la religion chrétienne » et non « partisans ». Cependant on dira avec des fréquences comparables « [adeptes](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=adeptes+du+positivisme%2Cpartisans+du+positivisme&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cadeptes%20du%20positivisme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpartisans%20du%20positivisme%3B%2Cc0) du positivisme » et « partisans du positivisme » ; dans le premier cas on insiste sur l'implication de la personne comme étant au niveau de la pratique ; dans le second on insiste sur l'implication comme étant au niveau de la théorie, de l'opposition qu'elle constitue en rapport avec des théories concurrentes.

On dit bien les  « [adeptes](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=adepte+du+cin%C3%A9ma%2Cadeptes+du+cin%C3%A9ma&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cadeptes%20du%20cin%C3%A9ma%3B%2Cc0) du cinéma » et cela ne semble pas relever des sens trouvés ci-dessus mais d'un troisième sens qui serait d'origine plus récente et que l'on trouve dans le [Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/adepte/1057).

> (Larousse) Personne qui privilégie et pratique une activité, 
>   un sport : Les adeptes de la planche à 
>   voile.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR / Pour faire simple:

« **adhérent** » = Membre d'un groupe (Par intérêt personnels)

> Je suis membre du club de piscine.

« **partisan** » = Membre d'un groupe (qui prend parti explicitement, qui défend une cause, qui milite) Exemple:

> Cette personne est partisan d'un parti politique.

« **adepte** » = Habitué à une activité. Exemple:

> Nous sommes adeptes du cinéma.

Comment: Cette courtisante persante n'est pas partisante de la cuisine catalante...

Comment: Ok, j'exagère, certains dictionnaires ont fini par accepter ce barbarisme.

Comment: Pardon? J'ai peur de ne pas avoir compris où vous vouliez en venir.

Comment: Cette courtisane persane n'est pas **partisane** de la cuisine catalane.

Comment: http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/partisan-t-a96689465

Comment: Les deux formes ne sont elles pas correctes ? Il me semble bien avoir vu aue `partisante` fonctionne également. https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/partisan_partisante/58396

Comment: Oui, la forme se rencontre parfois. Le Larousse est l'un des rares dictionnaire qui propose *partisante* comme féminin de *partisan*. Il indique quand même que cette forme est familière, la forme standard étant uniquement au masculin pour lui et donc *Cette personne est un partisan d'un parti politique*. Le masculin n'ayant pas de *t* final, on peut se demander ce qui pourrait le justifier au féminin. Tous les masculins en *-an* ayant un féminin l'ont en *-ane*. Un autre: *paysan/paysane*, pas *paysante*. Le TLFi ne propose que *partisane*, le Littré cite *partisante* comme "moins correcte".

Comment: Ont peut voir avec Google Ngram qu'une forme clairement incorrecte comme *partisanne* se rencontre plus souvent aujourd'hui que *partisante* : [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=partisante%2Cpartisanne%2Cpartisane&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpartisante%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpartisanne%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpartisane%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Très bien, merci d'avoir souligné ce point, j'ai mis à jour ma réponse avec `partisan` au lieu de `partisante`